# Returning the different length to maximize profit when cuttting a rod

Tags: java

My program have to display in what different lengths to cut a rod in order to maximize profit.

[image]

This is my function for the rod cutting:

It takes as parameter an array *lengths* (1 to 8), an array *profit (1,5,8,9,10,17,17,20)*, and the length of the rod.

```
public static void rodCut(int[] lengths, int[] profit, int len){
    
    int lengthInput = lengths.length-1;
    int[][] cuttingLength = new int[lengthInput + 1][len + 1];
    int[] chosenElement = new int[lengthInput + 1];
    int[][] maximum = new int[lengthInput + 1][len + 1];
    int numA;
    int numB=0;
    int a = 1;
    
    while(a <=lengthInput) {
        int i=0;
        while(i<=len) {
            numA = maximum[a - 1][i]; 
            if (i >= lengths[a]) {
                numB =  profit[a] + maximum[a - 1][i - lengths[a]];
            }
            maximum[a][i] = Math.max(numA,numB);
            if(numA<numB) {
                cuttingLength[a][i]=1;
            }
            else {
                cuttingLength[a][i]=0;
            }
            i++;
            numB=0;
        }
        a++;
    }
    
    //we represent the selected element with a 1, else, 0
    int z = lengthInput;
    int l = len;
    while(z>0) {
        if (cuttingLength[z][l] > 0){
            chosenElement[z] = 1;
            l = l - lengths[z];
        }
        else {
            chosenElement[z] = 0;
        }
          z--;  
    }
    
    //indicate which length it needs to be cut
    int j=1;
    String rods = "";
    String tmp = "";
    while(j<lengthInput+1) {
        if (chosenElement[j] == 1) {
            tmp+=lengths[j]+", ";
        }
        j++;
    }
    rods = tmp.substring(0,tmp.length()-2);
    System.out.print("\nLengths to be cut:  "+rods+"");
    
}
```

I am not getting the desired output when the length is large.

Suppose the length is 40.
The output should be : `Lengths to be cut: 2,2,2,2,2,6,6,6,6,6`

But i am getting: `Lengths to be cut: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8`

Comment: Can you add any sample outputs?

Comment: @SabareeshMuralidharan i have edited the post and added a sample output.

Comment: May be you can refer https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/cutting-a-rod-dp-13/

Comment: I took your code and tried it myself. I'm getting the correct output for input 9. Maybe you are inputting your arrays wrong?

Comment: @SabareeshMuralidharan i already checked this.  it only displays the maximum profit and not the different lengths it needs to be cut.

Comment: Yes, you can modify it, when you find the max value profit[i] get the coordinates via length[i]

Comment: @maloomeister. yeah my inputting arrays were wrong.  but still i cannot get the desired output.